Quantification of Complexity in Trading Systems
I am trying to define and quantify the complexity of a trading system, where complexity is measured by degrees of freedom as the sum of its rules and unique data points.
where:
degrees of freedom = rules + data points

and this may be used in (see explanation by Pardo Design, Testing, and Optimization of Trading Systems, 1992)
Calculation of the degrees of freedom = whole data sample –
rules and conditions – data consumed by rules and conditions

In this context I am trying to properly quantify the cases where data points should and should not be counted twice.
I have seen the application of this rule described (see Trading Systems  A New Approach to System Development and Portfolio Optimisation By Urban Jaekle, Emilio Tomasini 2nd Edition, 2019) in examples similar to SMA(20), close + SMA(10), close equals 22 degrees of freedom, because "data points used twice in calculations are only counted once." while SMA(20), open and SMA(10), close have 30 degrees of freedom.
I would like to understand the objective rule that determines when a data point is considered distinct.
Based on this rule, would SMA(20), close and EMA(10), close have 20 or 30 data points?
If I derive EMA using SMA, calculating both with the same price points (P1, P2, ..., Pn) over a period of days (n), should I only count the data points once?
SMA = (P1 + P2 + ... + Pn) / n
EMA = (P1 * (2 / (n + 1)) 
       + P2 * (2 / (n + 1)) * (1 - (2 / (n + 1))) 
       + P3 * (2 / (n + 1)) * (1 - (2 / (n + 1)))^2 
       + ... 
       + Pn * (1 - (2 / (n + 1)))^(P1 - n))

What are the objective rules that help define when a data point is unique and when should datapoints not be counted twice?

I am trying to properly quantify the complexity of a trading system that is the sum of its rules and unique data points <-- So, there is no source for your definition of complexity?

The complexity I'm referring to is specific to this trading system and is defined as the sum of its rules and unique data points. This framework is a way to measure the number of degrees of freedom in the system, based on how often data points are reused in calculations. I am looking for clarification on the objective rules for when a data point is considered 'unique' or 'reused' in order to quantify it more accurately.

Yes, I got that. I was asking for a source (documentation or a website) on where you have seen this definition of complexity before, but you answered it (implicitly) yourself (and through your edit).

Thanks. I have attempted to improve my question into a simpler related question here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/80601/degrees-of-freedom-in-moving-average-crossover-strategies-with-varying-parameter.

any thougths @nbbo2 or @pleb?
